# How would skeptics know that a single-engine plane could not destroy a falling meteor?

Tags: internal-consistency, astronomy, explosions, aircraft, meteor

So I'm writing a story and decided to use Hida Furukawa as the location. It has a high school with a field of 650 ft that theoretically could be used for a small aircraft to be use to take off. In the story, a meteor falling that can wipe the town out. A man decides to fly a plane into the meteor with some explosives on it to destroy the meteor and is successful at the cost of his "life."

I intentionally put that in quotes. As he is some dimensional traveler that controlled the meteor to fall. He staged a fake heroic death to jump into another dimension. In my story, I want to know what science/astronomer critics would say to give clues to how unnatural this is, so it helps the female protagonist believe that he is still alive and probably in another dimension.

**Note** (08/02/18)
Based on everyone's feedback, I've changed location to Kakamigahara, Gifu Japan. It has a private airport that is sometimes used by the Japanese Airforce :) While I'm not going the fun with W-59 @CortAmmon suggested, I was tempted since I'd have access to planes that could fly higher lol.

Comment: Just be aware that scientists are not experts in "other dimensions". Their expertise is pretty much limited to what we can observe

Comment: Hello Jemiloii and welcome to Worldbuilding! Congratulations for a asking a clear and interesting question. I would think that a small aircraft and a few kilograms of explosive won't do much against a meteorite coming down with enough kinetic energy (some tens of kilotons of TNT) to obliterate a small town, but I look forward to reading the answers of knowledgeable members of the community.

Comment: @Raditz_35: The question is not about the other dimensions; the question asks what would skeptic critics have to say about a small aircraft with a bomb on board stopping a large-ish meteorite bound for an innocent Japanese town.

Comment: Scientists and astronomers are going to have a lot less trouble with this plot than explosive experts and pilots.

Comment: a meteor that could destroy a town will not be stopped by a small plane maybe if your dimensional traveler has a nuke in his pocket but even then the damage will turn the town into rubble and lots of people will die but maybe this Impact calculator will help you get a better size http://simulator.down2earth.eu/planet.html?lang=en-US

Comment: Critics would say: "As smart as Independence Day but without the lovable antics of Will Smith"

Comment: Didn't someone already make a movie about this, with Bruce Willis and Liv Tyler?

Comment: @RonJohn I don't know to be honest. I know there is an anime where a guy and girl somehow used time traveling dreams to save a town from being wiped out. I think it was called "Your Name"

Comment: https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120591/ "After discovering that **an asteroid** the size of Texas **is going to impact Earth** in less than a month, N.A.S.A. recruits a misfit team of deep core drillers **to save the planet**." Your story is *Armageddon* in Japan.  Which is definitely not wrong/bad; just note that it exists...  :)

Comment: _Even if_ we can prove how impossible it is, that still doesn't prove that your "hero" knew that to be the case. As long as you can't prove that he didn't genuinely expect his plan to work (or at least have a shot), the heroic attempt is not disproven.

Comment: @CreedArcon Not to mention a nuke over Japan might be interpreted as North Korean aggression, and dimensional antics at that point should be pretty low on your list of concerns.

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri It's rare to see a work of fiction that accurately portrays aviation.

Comment: "He staged a fake heroic death to jump into another dimension." Sounds like something from Quantum Leap.

Comment: @Flater AIUI the point is that it *does* work, and thus that it can't have been what it appeared to be.

Comment: The question is confusing. So, our pilot jumps to the new dimension. But, what do you mean by he "controlled the meteor to fall." Does the meteor go into the other dimension? Because a small plane with explosives sure can't stop it. @jemiloii You have the right movie, but they save the people in the town from being wiped out by tricking them into evacuating them; they don't actually save the town itself.

Comment: @ohwilleke The question is, after the pilot successfully stops it, somehow, what would skeptics say about it. Of course a little plane, cannot stop the meteor. Everyone has provided wonder insights and the math behind it. :)

Answer (score 64, accepted):

I’m going to address this as a general question about using airplanes to stop meteors, rather than the very plot specific way the question is worded.

Nope. For one very simple reason:

Speed.

Meteors are not the slow moving flaming behemoths of Hollywood. In reality they’ll be moving at or above Earth's escape velocity ([11km/s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_velocity#List_of_escape_velocities)) when they hit the atmosphere, and anything big enough to hit the ground with any destructive force wont have shed much of that speed by the time it does. This means that they’ll clear the distance from your plane’s operational ceiling to the ground faster than you can twitch your joystick.

There are also serious concerns with the energy involved (no plane can carry enough energy to stop an impactor from impacting) and the fact that by the time it hits the plane it will already likely be in fragments.

On the other hand: your extradimensional guy can be using any number of weird technobabbly things to achieve his goal, employing advanced tech to make sure he’s in the path of the meteor and absorbing the energy to make the jump, but then it would appear more like he was just very, very unlucky (or weirdly prescient) rather than demonstrably heroic.

EDIT FOR A FUN NOTE:

If the meteor were large enough to not be completely in pieces before it hit the ground it would also compress the air underneath it to such an extent that people would be incinerated *before* the meteor crushed them. Physics!

Comment: It's moving at cosmic speeds while outside the atmosphere, but it won't hit the ground with that speed. Or so I would think. It will hit the ground with hyper? super? sonic speed, though.

Comment: @Alexp: that’s why I lowballed it to 6 km/s instead of the minimum 7 that extraorbital objects hit the atmosphere at. The simple truth is that they just don’t have time to shed much speed.

Comment: @AlexP: That [meteor in Russia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chelyabinsk_meteor#Atmospheric_entry) some years back only slowed down to about 15km/s(from 30km/s) before breaking apart. The [world's fastest plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_airspeed_record) maxed out at about 1km/s.

Comment: @Giter: I stand corrected. Thank you.

Comment: @AlexP: Depends on the size of the meteor.  Something like the one caught on camera by a Norwegian skydiver will be just a falling rock, and will only hurt if it lands on your head: https://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/science/space/10742854/Meteorite-narrowly-misses-Norwegian-skydiver.html  The Chelyabinsk meteor, OTOH, fragmented at 29.7 km, well above any altitude reachable by a small plane: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chelyabinsk_meteor  So fragments hit the ground at fairly low speed, but the damage was caused by the air burst, when it was moving at ~18.6 km/s.

Comment: As it stated in the question, there is an actor who "controlled the meteor to fall". Which means he can possibly direct the meteor precisely to hit the plane.

Comment: @Alexander: He can, but it would look at best like a freak accident and at worst like he planned to get hit by the meteor. The first is freakishly unlikely, the second is patently ridiculous. There is no scenario where he looks like he heroically saved the town.

Comment: @jamesqf 30 km is well above the altitude reachable by practically *any* airplane, let alone what could be reached quickly. Jetliners normally cruise at around 10-12 km (some 30-35 thousand feet).

Comment: @AlexP Joe Bloggs is right. Suppose the rock is moving at even just a measly 5 km/s relative to the Earth. The Karman line is at 100 km, and that's the altitude at which "space" officially begins. If unimpeded by the thickening air, the asteroid would need 20 seconds to get from there to ground. While in reality the asteroid *will* be impeded by the atmosphere, (1) it will be moving much faster than that, and (2) the atmosphere doesn't become thick enough to truly matter before you get quite close to the ground. It just won't have time to slow down by any appreciable amount in the atmosphere.

Comment: We should not forget, the destructive energy of the meteor comes from the sudden deceleration. For that, it doesn’t matter whether the deceleration happens when hitting the ground or when being stopped by a plane (if that was possible). It still would release the energy and cause devastation. In fact, nuclear weapons are ignited high up in the air, because that will cause *more* destruction than exploding on the ground…

Comment: @Michael Kjörling: Yes, that was my point :-)  I do have a pilot's licence and a Piper Cherokee, which is a typical small plane.  It cruises at about 140 kts (say 150 mph), but its best climb speed is closer to 80 mph.  At sea level on a cool day, you might climb at 1000 feet per minute, but that drops fairly quickly with altitude.  It's a bit of work to get much above 12-13K ft.  IOW, nowhere near fast or high enough, even if you were in the plane with the engine running.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling - 30km is within range of a select few kinds of plane: many military planes, of course, and back when it was flying would have been not that far beyond the range of Concorde (the official service ceiling was 18.3km, but obviously such figures depend heavily on load, etc ... and if one specific meteor reached that height, then 20km for another seems very plausible), but clearly the kind of plane a random private individual might have to hand in an emergency situation is not going to be one of them. (Unless the private individual happens to be Burt Rutan, for example)

Answer (score 30):

**Not possible because meteorites move with [11 to 72 km/s](https://www.amsmeteors.org/meteor-showers/meteor-faq/#3). The best chemical explosive octanitrocubane create shockwaves with [10 km/s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octanitrocubane)**.

This means if the shockwave of the entering meteorite is not powerful enough to disintegrate it (as it often happens), chemical explosives can't do it.
When the hit would trigger the explosives immediately (which it cannot), the meteorite simply *outruns(!)* the explosive gases.

**How can a meteorite be destroyed?**

Let's say it is the same size like the [Chelyabinsk meteor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chelyabinsk_meteor), 20 m diameter and 10 000 ton weight.

*Heat*.
One possibility is to try to vaporize it, we need 3000°C to vaporize most stones. Stone has a specific heat capacity of ~1 kJ/kg*K, so we need 3 MJ/kg yielding 30 TJ ($30 \cdot 10^{12}$Joule) to vaporize the meteorite. If we could use the full energy of the most massive bomb ever built, the [Tsar Bomba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsar_Bomba), we have 20 Petajoule ($20 \cdot 10^{15}$ Joule) of energy available which would be sufficient. Problem:  The duration of the explosion was 39 nanoseconds which is equivalent to 0.39 millimeters of meteorite path, so we would need pinpoint precision.

*Pressure*
Another option is a powerful enough shockwave. You only need to split the meteorite in small enough parts that the atmosphere can vaporize them. So apart from being powerful enough *it must be dispersed in sufficient height* because otherwise your city is hit like a shotgun.

Even if we have a nuclear weapon, we still have many problems:

- Trigger: We would need a trigger with nanosecond precision to detonate the bomb exactly when it is needed.
- Distance: We would need a distance measuring method which would be able to accurately estimate something which is flying faster than a bullet.
- Path convergence: 20 m diameter is very, very small, you pass that in less of a second in the slowest airplane. How exactly do you find the exact path?
- Height: It does not matter if you destroy the meteorite in 5 km height because half a second later the debris will blow away your town. You need at least intercept it at stratosphere height (20 km).

**No, it is not possible. It is even a formidable task for today's technology**.

Comment: All these problems are because our atmosphere is a VERY good defense system.  Anything that beats it are extremely catastrophic and are well beyond our ability to defend against.

Comment: *"20 m diameter is very, very small, you pass that in less of a second in the slowest airplane"* Actually, 20 m/s sounds like about the lower limit for maneuverability in the motor airplane I fly. You're teetering on the brink of an aerodynamic stall around 50-60 km/h indicated airspeed in that particular one (better hope you don't get a gust of tailwind!), but around that speed, it's still controllable. I'm not sure I'd call what you're doing at that point *flying*, though... it's more that you're avoiding literally (not proverbially, but really literally) falling out of the sky.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Antonov AN-2 :). But it is mostly intended as rule of thumb to show how damn small the path is, so I said *less of a second*, allowing faster aircraft.

Comment: @ThorstenS. I agree. My comment was intended more to illustrate that it's still "barely possible" (and as a bonus, that airplane might actually be able to get airborne in those 650 ft without too much trouble if employing short-field takeoff techniques; it wouldn't have time to *climb* very far, though).

Comment: Of course, after exploding a Tsar Bomba at a hight a small aircraft can reach, it will be mostly irrelevant if the asteroid was destroyed, as the town will no longer exist anyway. Even if the explosion made the asteroid vanish completely (no debris).

Comment: You can use explosives on something moving faster than the shock front.  You just need to be in front of it when the explosives detonate so the object runs into the shock front rather than the shock front futilely chasing it down.

Comment: @LorenPechtel True, the problem is that the force of the explosion decreases quadratically with distance. Explosive damage is often surprisingly localized; many accidents without shrapnels cause people to lose finger(s)/hand(s)/arms(s), but remain otherwise unscathed. So you would need to trigger it very precisely -> the time/distance problem occurs again. Most explosives need blasting caps which have a much lower shockwave speed, so all in all chemical explosives are quite useless. Cort Ammon mentioned that the amount of energy in explosives compared to the kinetic energy is quite limited.

Comment: Re "split the meteorite in small enough parts that the atmosphere can vaporize them", that actually isn't going to help much.  Might even make things worse, as each of those fragments vaporizes, creating an air burst as with Chelyabinsk.  Bottom line is that the only way to divert a meteor is to do it before it reaches the atmosphere.

Comment: @ThorstenS. I wasn't disagreeing that the boom wouldn't be enough to matter, I was just objecting to the notion that the boom wouldn't connect in the first place.  We have the same problem with intercepting ballistic missiles--as we saw in Desert Storm detonating at the point of closest approach is useless, you need to aim in front of the inbound to hit it.

Comment: I strongly disagree with your computation. The Tsar bomba is nearly 1000 stronger than needed and would cause much more harm than the meteorite, so please use something more realistic. +++ These 39 nanoseconds seem completely irrelevant to me and these 0.39 millimeter even more. How could 0.39 mm be relevant to an object of 20 m diameter??? +++ That all said, your conclusion is surely right.

Comment: @Loren: "As we saw in Desert Storm"--what event are you referring to? If it's the Scud killing 28 American soldiers after being missed by a Patriot battery, that incident was caused by compounding errors in calculating time after 100+ hours of operation. That resulted in the radar being unable to track the inbound, and was unrelated to the mechanical problem of where to detonate the interceptor warhead in the flight path of the Scud. At no point (in that case, there could be another) was "in front of the inbound" vs. "point of closest approach" a conceptual question or source of error.

Comment: @clyf No, I'm talking about the multiple cases where a Patriot **did** "intercept" the inbound and did nothing to it because it detonated at the point of closest approach.  When you're shooting at a sufficiently fast-moving target you have to set off your warhead in **front** of it and let the inbound run into the debris, if the inbound is moving faster than the detonation velocity of your explosive it can go off in contact and still do nothing.

Comment: **Interesting**. Is this your source? http://scienceandglobalsecurity.org/archive/sgs04lewis.pdf#page=57

Answer (score 21):

The answer is no.  And if you really feel like it, you can ignore the explosives entirely.

In physics, we can always choose our frame of reference to simplify the problem.  Let's take our frame of reference to be that of the meteor.  If it is traveling at 6km/s with respect to the earth (a conservative estimate made by Joe Bloggs that I like), that means that, from the meteor's point of view, the plane is traveling at 6km/s towards it!  A [Cesna 172](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cessna_172) has a mass of roughly 1100kg.  At 6km/s that's about 40,000MJ of energy.  [TNT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TNT) releases around 4MJ/kg, so the kinetic energy alone accounts for about 1000kg of TNT.

**In other words, the energy from your relative velocity with respect to the meteor is equivalent to the explosive energy you'd have if you made your entire plane out of TNT!**

Now the energy required to level a town is on the order of nuclear weapons.  You're talking hundreds if not thousands of tons of TNT equivalent.  Your plane's energy is pretty darn minuscule by comparison.  Destroying a town is on the rough order of 1-2 MT of TNT equiv. so your plane is something like 0.1% of the mass that this meteor has.

> "Do you know how much damage this bulldozer would suffer if I allowed it to roll straight over you Mr. Dent?"
>
> "How much?"
>
> "None at all." - Hitchiker's Guide to the Galaxy

Also, note that the ceiling for a Cesna 172 is about 4.5km.  That means that you will hit the meteor at most 0.75 seconds before it impacts.  Most of the meteor is going to... well.. continue on to its destination.  It's not going to have the time it needs to pick up tangental velocity to spread the impact away from the town.

Comment: Sounds like he would need a nuked tied to the aircraft and it would need to some how go higher than 4.5km. The nuke would probably be too heavy for the Cesna 172 at that point haha. At which point, the nuke is just as big of a threat as the meteor.

Comment: Yeah, for some reason, I feel like if the protagonist showed up with a [W-59](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W59) in hand, I'd have to start questioning his status as a protagonist.

Comment: A Cesna could lift off with that XD, well he isn't the protagonist of this story. This is actually the start of it. He is just doing his usually, fake an epic death and dip strategy.

Comment: Of course, it probably doesn't help that a Cesna 172's ceiling is almost the ideal height for setting off a W-59 for maximum damage (thanks to [Nukemap](https://nuclearsecrecy.com/nukemap/))

Comment: a Cessna 172 won't take off in 650 ft without a really strong headwind, though.  Source: about 200 hours in 172s.

Comment: Forget the 650 ft ground roll @ErinAnne, and consider that it'd have to be at the end of a high school field. Who in their right mind would park a Cessna anywhere near a high school? Seems to me that if you're lucky you'll only have to do a *really* thorough preflight every time...

Comment: +1 for the Hitch reference, it's really a solid example of exactly why a light aircraft has zero likelihood of impeding a meteorite. I'd also compare it to attempting to stop a bullet with a paper airplane. saying "what if I laced the paper airplane with nitroglycerine?" doesn't really affect the outcome.

Answer (score 15):

**He fakes it with his dimensional powers**

To answer your question NO he will not make it in time; and even if he did blow up the meteor the fallout would kill everybody anyway

BUT

IF the dimensional traveler could just use his powers to take a huge part out of the meteor into another dimension. then blow what’s left up with his plane and make it look like he did it. then fake his death for the whole world to see and just be left confused

The science/astronomer critics will be baffled as to why they are not dead based on the size of the meteor and that could be the protagonist clue for her to believe he’s alive. It’s both sound of mind and helps you avoided the “jumped the shark moment”

Comment: Haha, thanks for the input, while it doesn't answer the question of what critics would say, this does help make the situation more believable!

Comment: I was just going to write this same thing.  Yes, the "science/astronomer critics" would be baffled as to how the plane with explosives could have stopped the meteor and its effects.  Since there was video of the event they know it was successful, they just won't be able to figure out how (unless they know about extra dimensions.)

Comment: Now this is an answer.

Comment: How is this the answer? This is *basically just describing the setup of the question*.

Answer (score 9):

When any object comes from space into our atmosphere it undergoes ablation - the intense friction and pressure (from  air compression) generates heat and corrodes the object away. That's why the smallest bodies never reach the ground, disintegrating in the upper atmosphere. Larger objects may hit the ground after losing some mass to ablation.

Blowing up a falling meteor may actually be a good idea. By tearing it into chunks more surface would be exposed to ablation, and the smaller pieces might disintegrate in the upper atmosphere.

However, a town destroying asteroid might be too massive and tenacious for a simple explosive. Also it is moving too fast - these things enter the atmosphere at multiples of the speed of sound. Last but not least you need to intercept it pretty high in the atmosphere, or in space preferably. This is a job for missiles of the heaviest kind - we are talking ICBM's here.

Your character's feat will not take a scientist to debunk. Anyone with high school knowledge of physics will see that this is farfetched enough even for Holywood.

Comment: While friction does contribute to heating a meteor, most of it comes from compression of the air that literally doesn't have time to go out of the way and gets rammed against the meteor. Not that it invalidates the answer, of course, as both do pretty much the same for an observer anyway.

Answer (score 4):

After everyone being a downer I'm go to help you out here. Realistically? No he couldn't do it. Technically? Of course, he could use the caloric energy contained within 11,048,505,945,548,076,923.077 chocolate chip cookies.

This is all assuming that this is a very large meteor traveling at 41.5 Km/s (average meteor speed is between 11 and 72Km/s so lets cut that in half) and is made out of iron and has a radius of 30.89km and is also striking at a 90 degree angle for maximum energy deliverance so it's powerful enough to destroy the whole of Hida-Furukawa. (These numbers are from http://down2earth.eu/impact_calculator/, fun little tool.) This is all assuming that region of japan is mostly made of igneous rock which was an assumption of my part.

The energy of this meteor at such a velocity upon impact is about 3.60811375*10^21 J which can be converted into 8.6178316375275x10^20 cal and the all powerful god google told me that there are about 78 calories in a chocolate chip cookie. Divide the necessary amount of energy to stop the meteor to stop the meteor by the amount of energy in a cookie and you find how many cookies you need.

TL;DR If you ate and absorbed 100% of the energy in 11,048,505,945,548,076,923.077(ish) chocolate chip cookies you would be able to stop the meteor with your fist and still have room for a snack.

Refs:
Speed of a meteor: https://www.amsmeteors.org/meteor-showers/meteor-faq/

Meteor size and density needed: http://down2earth.eu/impact_calculator/

Calories per chocolate chip cookie: I dunno ask google

Comment: Clearly those cookies are not good enough the calorie count is way too low to have enough chocolate. https://www.sweetstreet.com/store/specials/sandys-amazing-chocolate-chunk-manifesto-cookie.html   390 calories each.

Comment: "3.60811375*10^21 J" doesn't sound particularly approximate to me. And how did that figure get 100,000 times more precise when converted into calories?

Comment: Curious whether simply burying the town in cookies might actually be effective at absorbing the impact to safe levels. 11 quintillion cookies has gotta be pretty shock-absorbent!

Comment: Having gone away and Done The Math, I estimate that if you attempted to bury the town in cookies to a 2 mile radius, with 11 quintillion cookies (45cubic-centimeters each based on a random number pulled off google) then you'd bury it to a depth of 1.5 trillion meters. This is a tower of yum that extends many many times further than the orbit of the moon. Needless to say, the town is completely destroyed as both the earth and the moon are devastated by a never ending hail of superheated deliciousness. But the meteor definitely isn't getting through that!

Comment: Further math indicates that if you placed that mass of cookies in open space, it'd collapse into a sphere slightly larger than the earth, before imploding into a dwarf planet comparable to the size of mars with around 1/10th the mass of ceres. It'd be massive enough you could walk around on its surface and It'd also briefly have an atmosphere as the water in the cookies boils away into space. It'd be a hell of a sight to see :P

Comment: How could you ever bake these cookies? There isn't enough room on earth for the mixing bowels. And even worse, where would you put the cooling racks?

Comment: @MichaelKjörling "how did that figure get 100,000 times more precise when converted into calories" ... that's a damned good question, given that a calorie[1] is defined as *exactly* 4.184 Joules, so you should only end up with 3sf more even if you start with an exact number...   [1] - at least, the thermochemical calorie is, which is the appropriate definition of calorie for this kind of use.

Comment: @NomadMaker If you're able to *heat* those cookies, then I imagine cooling them would be the least of your problems. I don't know what the specific heat capacity of chocolate chip cookies is, but I imagine it's a nonzero amount of energy per degree (Kelvin, Celsius, or what have you) per cookie, and honestly, *any* nonzero number multiplied by 11 quintillion is... pretty big.

Comment: For all of the people wondering how the caloric number got a few more decimal places, it's just because I used a different calculator to find that number and it rounded it differently. The joule number I didn't calculate and just pulled it from the meteor app so it isn't something I came up with. Also, assuming you have enough energy to bake that many cookies, the radiant energy from the cooking and than the cooling process may be enough to simply melt all of Hida-Furukawa anyway, making the entire thing more destructive than the meteor.

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be possible to break up an incoming meteorite if was simultaneously  hit by multiple high-speed projectiles fired by an array of electromagnetic railguns, such as the ones developed by the U.S. Navy. These projectiles would be traveling at 5600 mph (Mach 7.3) and each one would have 10.64 MJ of kinetic energy. I think a 5x5 array would do the trick.

The only catch is that you would need to know in advance when and where the meteorite was going to hit so you could set up the array in that area beforehand. You would also need a power plant nearby to supply the required electricity.